# Does an expected value command exist in R

Tags: r, statistics

I'm sure there must be a straight forward command for this, but I've searched and can't find one. How do I get the expected value from a vector?

Here are the values

```
y <- c(0.05, 0.01, -0.1)
```

And their probabilities

```
p <- c(0.2, 0.7, 0.1)
```

I can get `E(Y)` by doing

```
sum(y*p)
```

But I think there is probably a command for it right, I just can't find it. Thanks!

Comment: Nope. That's is. When it's that easy, why implement a special command for it?

Comment: @MrFlick But think of the possibilities!  Feed `y` and `p` into a spline calculator, generate the distribution function, and *then* calculate the expected value by applying calculus  to said function!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `weighted.mean`:

```
weighted.mean(y, p)
# [1] 0.007
```

Comment: Thanks this was great. This lead me to find Hmisc and SDMTools, unfortunately neither of their weighted variances worked as expected.

Hmisc's wtd.var(y, weights=p, normwt=TRUE) returned 0.0022815 while SDMTools' wt.var(y, p) returned 0.003306522

What I'd like to find now though is a command that returns this
weighted.mean(y^2, p)-weighted.mean(y, p)^2

If anyone knows of a library let me know, thanks!

Comment: Did you mean var(y) ? @TimHUK

Answer (score 5):

Here's another option:

```
> c(y %*% p)
[1] 0.007
```