# How to use prop.table() output to calculate expect value

Tags: r, statistics, weighted-average

The title is rather self-explanatory. Basically, I have a `prop.table` object and  I'd like to use the information from the `prop.table` to calculate the expected value `E(Y)`.

Let's assume this is our data:

```
Y <- c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) # List of values

p <- c(0.082710, 0.111331, 0.093211, 0.110218, 0.085769, 0.117118, 
       0.085703, 0.109429, 0.092786,0.111725) # List of probabilities
```

According to another [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26959127/does-an-expected-value-command-exist-in-r), expected value can be calculated in several ways using Base R functions.

But how can I perform the same action if the values and their probabilities are already stored inside a `prop.table` object? This is my object:

```
>prop.table(table(data))
208 260 270 271 273 280 281 285 289 292 295 298 300 301 306 308 309 310 315 318 319 320 321 324 325 
  1   1   1   1   1   1   2   1   1   1   1   1   3   2   3   1   2   2   2   1   3   3   2   1   3 
326 328 330 331 332 334 336 337 338 339 340 341 342 343 344 345 346 347 348 349 350 351 352 353 354 
  4   2   1   5   3   1   6   3   4   4   3   6   1   6   5   4   1   3   3   2   5   1   6   5   3 
355 356 357 358 359 360 361 362 363 364 365 366 367 368 369 370 371 372 373 374 375 376 377 378 379 
  5   7   8   4   8   4   3   7   8  10   6   9  10   8   4   9  11   4   5   7   5  11  14   7  11 
380 381 382 383 384 385 386 387 388 389 390 391 392 393 394 395 396 397 398 399 400 401 402 403 404 
 14   9  14  12  16  12  12   6  11  14   8  17  17  15  18  13  19  15  22  12  17  15  13  19  14 
405 406 407 408 409 410 411 412 413 414 415 416 417 418 419 420 421 422 423 424 425 426 427 428 429 
 23  11  21  17  19  15  25  23  23  24  21  28  17  32  25  33  26  24  27  32  25  29  33  23  29 
430 431 432 433 434 435 436 437 438 439 440 441 442 443 444 445 446 447 448 449 450 451 452 453 454 
 24  26  25  35  39  40  27  32  28  36  32  32  42  20  39  42  27  38  35  37  35  36  32  37  41 
455 456 457 458 459 460 461 462 463 464 465 466 467 468 469 470 471 472 473 474 475 476 477 478 479 
 51  38  35  46  41  39  48  43  37  47  42  52  56  44  46  44  58  53  46  69  38  47  52  68  52 
480 481 482 483 484 485 486 487 488 489 490 491 492 493 494 495 496 497 498 499 500 501 502 503 504 
 51  52  58  52  57  51  61  50  55  61  55  64  58  52  53  58  60  64  47  48  47  47  49  66  48 
505 506 507 508 509 510 511 512 513 514 515 516 517 518 519 520 521 522 523 524 525 526 527 528 529 
 62  48  55  55  57  64  46  52  41  49  47  54  58  59  52  59  52  74  46  61  51  59  59  59  66 
530 531 532 533 534 535 536 537 538 539 540 541 542 543 544 545 546 547 548 549 550 551 552 553 554 
 57  61  50  79  62  58  61  48  38  57  54  46  54  60  55  45  38  54  46  45  45  44  40  43  70 
555 556 557 558 559 560 561 562 563 564 565 566 567 568 569 570 571 572 573 574 575 576 577 578 579 
 42  55  50  40  48  57  45  42  52  56  52  30  42  37  43  39  28  39  33  28  44  42  39  35  34 
580 581 582 583 584 585 586 587 588 589 590 591 592 593 594 595 596 597 598 599 600 601 602 603 604 
 36  46  38  38  28  33  30  24  49  29  21  25  26  27  23  29  30  22  27  28  26  23  22  22  20 
605 606 607 608 609 610 611 612 613 614 615 616 617 618 619 620 621 622 623 624 625 626 627 628 629 
 18  23  20  22  22  23  23  20  18  24  19  17  19  20  12  12  19  15  18  16  15  13   8  10  13 
630 631 632 633 634 635 636 637 638 639 640 641 642 643 644 645 646 647 648 649 650 651 652 653 654 
 14  15  16   7  16  14  11  15  15   7   7   9  13   7   8   7   8   9   5   5   7   8   6   7   9 
655 656 657 658 659 660 661 662 663 664 665 666 667 668 669 670 671 672 673 674 675 676 677 678 679 
  2   5   3  10   5   6   7   3   8   7   4   3   4   1   1   7   2   2   8   3   5   3   2   1   1 
680 681 682 683 684 685 686 687 688 689 690 691 692 693 694 695 696 697 698 699 700 702 704 705 706 
  3   2   1   3   1   2   3   3   1   3   2   2   1   2   2   5   2   3   2   3   5   1   1   2   2 
707 708 709 710 711 712 716 720 722 723 726 727 728 732 733 744 748 751 764 825 
  2   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If

```
x <- prop.table(table(data))
```

then

```
Y <- as.numeric(names(x))
P <- x / sum(x)
```

So you can get expectation by either of two:

```
weighted.mean(Y, P)
sum(Y * P)
```